# CL_MEM_OBJECT_ALLOCATION_FAILURE error executing CL_COMMAND_NDRANGE_KERNEL

Tags: opencl, gpgpu

Have an OpenCL program that does a video processing. It works fine for small videos, however when the input has more then 200 frames OpenCL throws "CL_MEM_OBJECT_ALLOCATION_FAILURE error executing CL_COMMAND_NDRANGE_KERNEL" error after 210th frames on clEnqueueNDRangeKernel. I thought reason behind it could be unreleased buffers. But i controlled all.

Comment: by the way i tried the same code on windows machine which has worser GPU but it works fine on it. problem occurs on linux.also drivers are updated last drivers for both.

Comment: What is your question, by the way? And can we see some relevant code?

Comment: Also, run `CLInfo` and get the post the relevant memory specifications here (global_memory_size, local_memory_size, max_global_alloc_size, etc.)